# bash script not moving onto next command

Tags: bash, docker

I have a simple bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir server/ run:app -w 2
supervisord -c /usr/src/server/supervisord.conf -n
```

The script is supposed to launch the gunicorn service and then start supervisor. However when the script is called, only the gunciron service is started and not the supervisor service.

The script is being called as follows from a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install netcat && \
    apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server

COPY . usr/src/server
WORKDIR /usr/src

RUN pip install -r server/requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/server/start.sh
CMD ["/usr/src/server/start.sh"]
```

I have tried using the `&&` separator between the 2 commands as well, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Is `gunicorn` supposed to run in the background and return immediately?

Comment: You can put `&` on the end of the gunicorn line.

Comment: Are you aware why you should not run more than one service per container?

Comment: @emix I am assuming this is to reduce the risk if a container fails? My supervisor here is starting an rq worker to do calculations  based on incoming data and while gunciorn is serving a flask app. It would seem logical that one wouldn't start without the other ever and needs to be coupled, which is why I decided to tie the 2 together. Is this an issue?

Comment: @Anubhav it should work, but it's not considered good practice. nginx and gunicorn should typically run in separate containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash script will move on to the next command when the first command has finished running. `supervisord` will start when `gunicorn` exits.

To run Gunicorn in the background, pass the `--daemon` option.

```
#!/bin/bash

gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir server/ run:app -w 2 --daemon
supervisord -c /usr/src/server/supervisord.conf -n
```

However, this doesn't make much sense to me. Since you're running Supervisor, why aren't you running Gunicorn from Supervisor? Starting daemons is Supervisor's job.

Comment: Yes you’re right. I should be running gunicorn from within supervisor. Thanks for your help!